# println! to print a 2 digit integer

Tags: rust

I would like println! to turn my integer into a 2 digit number, adding a 0 in the front if needed.

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:}", 7);
    println!("{:}", 12);
}
```

the expected result should be:

```
07
12
```

Any format parameters to be used here or should I create a specific Display trait in this case?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the leading zeros like so:

```
println!("{:02}", 7);
```

---

You can also check the different formatting possibilities in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#usage):

```
assert_eq!(format!("Hello {:+}!", 5), "Hello +5!");
assert_eq!(format!("{:#x}!", 27), "0x1b!");
assert_eq!(format!("Hello {:05}!", 5),  "Hello 00005!");
assert_eq!(format!("Hello {:05}!", -5), "Hello -0005!");
assert_eq!(format!("{:#010x}!", 27), "0x0000001b!");
```